# When I close bootstrap4 modal Console show '[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took xxms'

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I use display:grid wrap with many tables, when I clcik BS4 modal button, it's doesn't show any problem in Console but I left the modal,show Violation message.

- I think bootstrap4  Modal need to deal with table render, so Chrome
  show the  Violation warn message.
- many tables case Dom tree broken.

Is there any good idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Where is your code ? Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have update it